# Can any one please tell me the difference between fromEvent observable and button click event

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

```
  // component.ts

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.addBtn?.nativeElement, "click").subscribe((res) => {
      console.log("response for the fromElement", res);
      this.appendElement();
    });
  }

  addItem() {
    this.appendElement();
  }

  appendElement() {
    let el = document.createElement("li");
    el.innerText = "Future web";

    // @ts-ignore
    document.getElementById("listContainer").appendChild(el);
  }
```

```html
    <!-- component.html -->

    <Button #addBtn>From Event</Button>
    <button (click)="addItem()">Inside </button>
    <ul id="listContainer">
        <!-- generating dynamic <li> elements -->
    </ul>
```

In the above code, I generate dynamic li and display it in the list but I'm not able to get the exact difference between both

Comment: fromEvent is rxJs function is more powerful when you want to do some computation work on some event trigger. like if you want to detect 2, 3.. clicks by user.

Comment: Can you please tell me the real time example in which fromEvent wins

Comment: You can check this conference talk which uses `fromEvent` which can then help to accomplish a complex task. https://youtu.be/hsr4ArAsOL4

Answer (score 1):

[fromEvent](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent) is rxJs function used to create `Observable` from DOM events. Hence it allows us to use all RxJs powerful features. It's very useful when you want to do some computation work on events.
We can even combine two or more Observables created by two or more DOM Nodes events.

One of the common use cases of `fromEvent` is when you want to reduce API calls while [searching](https://medium.com/aviabird/rxjs-reducing-number-of-api-calls-to-your-server-using-debouncetime-d71c209a4613) on our webpage.

`fromEvent` is also useful when you want to listen to events on multiple DOM Nodes. You can just pass the ArrayLike Nodes list as a first parameter.

`(click)` is the normal click event just like in JavaScript, which triggers every time users click on a target DOM node. [more here](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding)

So comparing both use `fromEvent` when you want to perform some operation on DOM events

Comment: we can also achieve debounce with out fromEvent can you please tell me the real time example in which fromEvent wins

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-reacting-to-multiple-inputs-using-rxjs-s-combinelatest.. Its not about wins. It's about enabling reactive style to reduce writing complex code

Answer (score 1):

`fromEvent` just wraps the `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` calls in an Observable. Such that it will `addEventListener` when subscribed, and `removeEventListener` when unsubscribed:

Basically:

```js
import { Observable, take } from 'rxjs';

function fromEvent(target, type) {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    const handler = e => subscriber.next(e);
    console.log('event listener added');
    target.addEventListener(type, handler);
    return () => {
      console.log('event listener removed');
      target.removeEventListener(type, handler);
    };
  });
}

const clicks$ = fromEvent(button, 'click');

clicks$.pipe(take(3)).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference b/w the two is that:

**fromEvent** is an Observable that emits events of a specific type coming from the given event target. It is part of rxjs library.
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent

While the **click event** is actually an angular created wrapper for the normal HTML click DOM event.

For minor use cases as above, click event will be the right way to go where you are expecting the trigger from specific known elements.